# Ordering of keys in dictionaries using SymPy

Tags: dictionary, sympy, commutativity

I have the following problem with my code. I start off with a polynomial (f = 3x+2y+xy), and want to store the coefficients and variables in separate lists (I want to be able to change this polynomial f, so don't want to predetermine which variables I will use). Crucially I'd like to preserve ordering of the variables under these operations in the code below.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import *

x,y = symbols('x,y', commutative=False)

f = 3*x+2*y+x*y
fdict = f.as_coefficients_dict()
print(fdict)
print(fdict.keys())    
print(sum(fdict.keys()))
```

Yet the output here is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {y: 2, x: 3, x*y: 1})
dict_keys([y, x, x*y])
x + x*y + y
```

I input the terms with variables in the order: `x, y, x*y`
Then the dictionary orders the keys as: `y, x, x*y`
And the summation of the keys is in the order: `x, x*y, y`.

Could somebody explain what is happening here and how I should alter my code to ensure the ordering remains the same? (I am using Python 3.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly commutative=False applies only to multiplication and not addition so it has no effect here.

There are several different orderings to be aware of. One is the *internal* order of the terms in an `Add`. The other is the order in which terms are *displayed* which is not necessarily the same:

```
In [35]: e = sum(fdict.keys())

In [36]: e
Out[36]: x⋅y + x + y

In [37]: e.args
Out[37]: (x, y, x⋅y)

In [38]: str(e)
Out[38]: 'x*y + x + y'

In [39]: print(e)
x*y + x + y
```

Depending on what you are doing you might only care about one of these or you might care about both.

To keep the *internal* order unchanged you can use `Add` with `evaluate=False`:

```
In [43]: list(fdict)
Out[43]: [y, x, x⋅y]

In [44]: e2 = Add(*fdict, evaluate=False)

In [45]: e2.args
Out[45]: (y, x, x⋅y)

In [46]: e2
Out[46]: x⋅y + x + y
```

You can see that Add with evaluate=False preserves the order of `fdict`. However the expression still does not display in that order. You can change the display order to respect the internal ordering:

```
In [47]: init_printing(order='none')

In [48]: e2
Out[48]: y + x + x⋅y
```

Of course the above all presumes that your `f` had the correct order in the first place but for that you need to use `Add` again:

```py
In [50]: init_printing(order='none')

In [51]: f = Add(3*x, 2*y, x*y, evaluate=False)

In [52]: f
Out[52]: 3⋅x + 2⋅y + x⋅y

In [53]: fdict = f.as_coefficients_dict()

In [54]: print(fdict)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {x: 3, y: 2, x*y: 1})

In [55]: e3 = Add(*fdict, evaluate=False)

In [56]: e3
Out[56]: x + y + x⋅y
```

Lastly the ordering of dictionaries is something that is controllable in recent versions of Python but in previous versions the ordering of a `dict` was always unpredictable. SymPy has existed long before dictionary order was meaningful so you should understand that any function/method like `as_coefficients_dict` which returns a `dict` is something that was *by design* not expected to return items in any well-defined order. You should not presume that any random function that happens to return a dict will give any guarantee about the ordering of the keys in that dict unless there is some documentation to that effect.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed and informative answer! This will be a massive help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want two lists of coefficients and factors of terms in the order you give them, then you can skip making the sum (i.e. don't add them) and use `as_coeff_Mul` instead of `as_coefficients_dict` and build your own dictionary:

```py
terms = [3*x,  2*y, x*y]
co = dict([i.as_coeff_Mul() for i in terms])
>>> co.items()
dict_items([(3, x), (2, y), (1, x*y)])
```